# Change Audio From Multple Audio Tracks Video

Tags: html, video, html5-video, audiocontext

i have videos with multiple audio tracks. i want to play the video and want change audio tracks from video. Is there any way to make this in html or there is html supported player for this?

Answer (score 1):

You should use the answer suggested by Hermes:

```
var video = document.getElementById("video");

for (var i = 0; i < video.audioTracks.length; i += 1) {
      video.audioTracks[i].enabled = false;
}
```

But in chrome for this to work you must enable the "Experimental Web Platform features" that you will find on chrome://flags/

Comment: This worked for me when using chrome: you must enable the "Experimental Web Platform features" that you will find on chrome://flags/. Also had to restart chrome.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to grab the audio track from an html5 video you can get the video element by id and then use the `.audioTracks` array and pass in the index of the track you with to access.

```
var video = document.getElementById("video");

for (var i = 0; i < video.audioTracks.length; i += 1) {
  video.audioTracks[i].enabled = false;
}
```

*MDN Docs:* [HTMLMediaElement.audioTracks](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement/audioTracks)

Furthermore, if you are looking to manipulate the audio, [William](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1152980/william) provides a good answer (https://stackoverflow.com/a/15286719/6931862) using [AudioContext](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AudioContext)

Below is the response provided in the link above, but with some edits to account for the updated adoption for `AudioContext` (used to be `webkitAudioContext`)

```
<script>

var video = document.createElement("video");
video.setAttribute("src", "ourMovie.mov");

video.controls = true;
video.autoplay = true;
document.body.appendChild(video);

var AudioContext = window.AudioContext || window.webkitAudioContext;
var audioCtx = new AudioContext();         // get access to audio context
var gainNode = audioCtx.createGain();
gainNode.gain.value = 1;                   // Change Gain Value to test
filter = audioCtx.createBiquadFilter();
filter.type = 2;                          // Change Filter type to test
filter.frequency.value = 5040;            // Change frequency to test

// Wait for window.onload to fire. See crbug.com/112368
window.addEventListener('load', function(e) {
  // Our <video> element will be the audio source.
  var source = audioCtx.createMediaElementSource(video); 
  source.connect(gainNode);
  gainNode.connect(filter);
  filter.connect(audioCtx.destination);

}, false);


</script>
```

Comment: hello sir, thank you for reply. It works. But i cant get audioTracks things on chrome browser. is there any way that support in all browsers?

Comment: @Vishal, I've updated my response to show how to use `AudioContext` (available in all browsers) to get a reference to the audio and then how to connect that back to the video element.

Comment: Hello Sir, I got your response and it is working on all browser. i can see audio details   on script. but i want to enable option on video player to change audio tracks. like you can check multiple audio tracks video on safari or internet explorer. when the video have multiple audio then video player shows an option to change audio tracks except in chrome and firefox browser , i want to enable it.  Please help me on this. Thank You

Comment: For that sort of functionality I have not seen default UI elements, the only examples i've seen use `audioTracks` which is not universally supported. I think you will most likely have to have your own button that runs some JS to handle switching of the audio resource for the video element.

Answer (score 0):

[There is an API for it, but it's not very supported.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement/audioTracks) However, there is a plugin for [video.js](https://github.com/videojs/video.js/) called [videojs-audio-tracks](https://github.com/sprice/videojs-audio-tracks), but it still uses the `audioTracks` API, which isn't supported by Chrome, and needs manual enabling in Firefox.

Comment: hello sir, thank you for reply. It works. But i cant get audioTracks things on chrome browser. is there any way that support in all browsers?

Comment: As mentioned in my answer, this seems to be the only API that allows for this. It is not available in the Chrome browser, as also stated in my answer.